# Search Product Name in Each Product Translation table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say that I have Product Table(ID,Name), Language(ID, Code) and ProductTranslation table(ID, ProductID, LanguageID, Name) Now let say I have 10-20 Languages. I need to search product name in each of the language translation table and Select only the Name which matches the name,

```
 SELECT Name, 
        L.ID 
  FROM  Product P, 
        ProductTranslation PT, 
        Language L
  WHERE P.ID = PT.ProductID  
        AND PT.LanguageID = L.ID
        AND P.Name LIKE '%A%'+' ?????
```

Edit: Note P.Name include the default value if no language available

Comment: what is your search string?

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli Search can be in any language. Eng/French/Arabic. Product Table include default one

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to look at the name field in the product translation table.  However, you should be using standard join syntax, and you don't need the language table:

```
select pt.name as NameInLanguage, pt.id, p.name as ProductName
from ProductTransalation pt join
     Product p
     on pt.productId = p.productId
where pt.name like '%A%'
```